# How to store multiple SELECT values at once into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have this select-tag which contains five different options. I want the user to be able to select up to three of those options. When submitted they should be saved into a MySQL row where there are three different fields (I call them 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3') that can store the information.

```
<select name="tag" multiple>
<option value="iphone">iPhone</option>
<option value="ipad">iPad</option>
<option value="ipod">iPod</option>
<option value="imac">iMac</option>
<option value="ishuffle">iShuffle</option>
</select>
```

How can this be done? I also want to be able to let the system know that only up to three options can be chosen. Or should I use something different than a select-tag?

Thanks! Have a great day!

Comment: Do you have any php code written in hand for reading form fields and sending them into database? If yes, add it to your posting.

Comment: not sure of this, the tag "multiple" will do, but to save them try to name it "tag[]" thats array try to print_r($_POST['tag']); if the three selected show then that's it! if this now work post some more of your code.

Comment: to put limit to 3 selected, take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/c9CkG/25/

Comment: @kodewrecker Thanks for the link - it solved my issue regarding the max three options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple selection values passed to PHP by specifying the name of the form element to create an array,

```
<select name="tag[]" multiple>
```

This will cause `$_REQUEST['tag']` to be an array with multiple values in it, which you can then process.

There is not a way to specifiy a maximum number of options for a select multiple tag, so to restrict to the maximum number of items selected you would need to check the length of that array using

```
count($_REQUEST['tag']
```

And if greater than three prompt an error or discard the extraneous choices.

For a more user friendly approach you could also do that checking client side in javascript, however you'd still be advised to do the server side check.